# Event watcher while executing powershell invoke-expression

Tags: .net, powershell

is there some sort of event watch for Invoke-Expression in powershell?

Im truing to louch a executable, and need some aditional info about it, for example execution time and mostly important set timeout, so if expression runs too long it will stop executing?

Something like:

```
Function Run
{
    Start-Transcript -path "C:\test.txt" -append
    $start = 0
    $timeoutInSec = 10
    while
    {
       # something to increase time
       # if time > timeout kill process
       Invoke-Expression "C:\test.exe -verbose -page"   
    }
   Stop-Transcript
}
```

Comment: sorry I think I misunderstood your question; removed my answer

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is mainly single-threaded from an invocation perspective, so there is no easy way to invoke something and watch for it in parallel. However, you can use *PowerShell Jobs* and run commands in the background (with [`Start-Job`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)).
With this you can poll your job and cancel it if required.

Note: invoking jobs might have a performance impact which can lead to some overhead in overall execution time of your command, so depending on your scenario this might blur your actual intent, but when you are measuring multiple 10s of seconds instead of milliseconds this should be fine.

[`Measure-Command`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176899.aspx) can be used to get the overall execution time, though [`StopWatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) is way more accurate.